# Transcoding AVI to DNxHD mov – only outputting first few seconds of the video

Tags: ffmpeg, terminal

Trying to convert a non-interleaved AVI file into the DNxHD codec with a mov container. The command is working fine, but the output file is coming out at only 4 seconds long (it's supposed to be 1m 5s) Info below, any help would be hugely appreciated. I have a feeling it may be due to the fact that the AVI has a missing index, but my friend spent hours rendering this file out of blender and it would be a shame to have to do it again. Thanks in advance for any help on this – I am not very experienced with this software!

Here's the command and log:

```
ffmpeg -i /Users/***/Downloads/1MinuteIntro0001-3930.avi -fflags ignidx -map 0:v -c:v dnxhd -pix_fmt yuv422p -filter:v fps=60 -trellis 0 -profile:v dnxhr_lb -y 1_orbitalboom.mov

ffmpeg version 3.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.21)
configuration: --prefix='/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg@3.4/3.4.2' --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --disable-jack --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
libavutil 55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
libavcodec  57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat 57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
libavdevice 57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
libavfilter  6.107.100 / 6.107.100
libavresample  3. 7. 0 / 3. 7. 0
libswscale 4. 8.100 / 4. 8.100
libswresample  2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100
libpostproc 54. 7.100 / 54. 7.100
[avi @ 0x7fb6fb00be00] Non-interleaved AVI without index, switching to interleaved
Input #0, avi, from '/Users/***/Downloads/1MinuteIntro0001-3930.avi':
Duration: 00:01:05.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 851990 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo, bgr24, 4096x2048, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> dnxhd (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, mov, to '1_orbitalboom.mov':
Metadata:
encoder  : Lavf57.83.100
Stream #0:0: Video: dnxhd (DNXHR LB) (AVdh / 0x68645641), yuv422p, 4096x2048, q=2-1024, 200 kb/s, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
Metadata:
encoder  : Lavc57.107.100 dnxhd
frame= 1 fps=0.4 q=0.0 size=  0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=  frame=  15 fps=5.4 q=1.0 size= 9472kB time=00:00:00.20 bitrate=387848.5kbitsframe=  29 fps=8.8 q=1.0 size=  19200kB time=00:00:00.41 bitrate=377428.9kbitsframe=  42 fps= 11 q=1.0 size=  28672kB time=00:00:00.63 bitrate=370827.4kbitsframe=  56 fps= 13 q=2.0 size=  37632kB time=00:00:00.83 bitrate=369909.3kbitsframe=  69 fps= 14 q=2.0 size=  47360kB time=00:00:01.05 bitrate=369475.6kbitsframe=  83 fps= 15 q=3.0 size=  57600kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=367664.2kbitsframe=  98 fps= 17 q=4.0 size=  68608kB time=00:00:01.53 bitrate=366530.4kbitsframe= 112 fps= 17 q=5.0 size=  79104kB time=00:00:01.76 bitrate=366790.4kbitsframe= 127 fps= 18 q=5.0 size=  90112kB time=00:00:02.01 bitrate=366036.6kbitsframe= 141 fps= 19 q=7.0 size= 100608kB time=00:00:02.25 bitrate=366292.1kbitsframe= 155 fps= 19 q=8.0 size= 110848kB time=00:00:02.48 bitrate=365655.1kbitsframe= 169 fps= 20 q=9.0 size= 121344kB time=00:00:02.71 bitrate=365899.3kbitsframe= 183 fps= 20 q=11.0 size= 131584kB time=00:00:02.95 bitrate=365394.1kbitframe= 197 fps= 21 q=13.0 size= 142080kB time=00:00:03.18 bitrate=365621.8kbitframe= 212 fps= 21 q=17.0 size= 152320kB time=00:00:03.41 bitrate=365204.4kbitframe= 227 fps= 22 q=20.0 size= 163328kB time=00:00:03.66 bitrate=364898.0kbitframe= 242 fps= 22 q=24.0 size= 174592kB time=00:00:03.91 bitrate=365166.2kbitframe= 257 fps= 22 q=28.0 size= 185600kB time=00:00:04.16 bitrate=364898.8kbitframe= 272 fps= 23 q=31.0 size= 196608kB time=00:00:04.41 bitrate=364661.7kbitframe= 277 fps= 22 q=33.0 Lsize= 204982kB time=00:00:04.60 bitrate=365040.8kbits/s speed=0.37x  
video:204980kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000896%
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: Thanks, just updated to include the full log